# MVC Post Partial View Within View And Return to View With Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have my main view that uses a partial view to show a modal when a button is clicked. When the partial view within the view is posted, I want the partial view with the view to still be shown. But a message on the partial view saying the message has been submitted. But it always seems to return the message to a blank screen with return message on it. The main view is on a different controller to the partial view. Any ideas of what i may be doing wrong

Main View

```
More html here
@Html.Partial("_SendMessagePartial", message);
More html here
```

The partial view looks like this

```
@model MyProject.Models.InternalMessage

<div id="messageform">
    <!-- Modal -->
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "InternalMessage", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "messageform" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enquiry About @Model.RelatedCar.VehicleMake.Make, @Model.RelatedCar.VehicleModel.Model</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Message)
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(i => i.Message)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Message)

                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.VehicleID)

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Post of partial view controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string Create([Bind(Include = "ID,FromUserID,ToUserID,Message,DateSent,DateRead,Read,VehicleID,RelatedCompanyID")] InternalMessage internalmessage)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.InternalMessage.Add(internalmessage);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return "You message has been sent to the vehicle owner";
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have just read a bit about unobtrusive ajax, looks like that may solve the issue

Comment: Can you confirm if your page have `jquery` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` js files both referenced?

Comment: You have wrapped the `Ajax.BeginForm` in `<div id="messageform">` so when you post you replace everything inside the div (including the form) with the returned message.

Comment: @tweray I do have both jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax

Comment: @StephenMuecke That was my desired method, after the form has been submitted in the partial view, i wanted to leave the modal open with a success message, then i planned to automatically close the modal after a couple of seconds

Comment: In which case you would need the place the `<div id="messageform">` outside the form - `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...) {...} <div id="messageform"></div>` so the returned message does not replace the form